# Process output in Yii Framework

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have an ajax submit button as follows,

```
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
        '>', $this->createUrl('/shop/category/nextCategory&id=16&store=true&gift_store='.$_GET['gift_store'].'&startValue='.$start_value.'&endValue='.$endValue), array(
        'type'=>'GET',
        'update'=>'#test',
        'beforeSend' => 'function(){
                        alert("beforeSend");
                        }',
        'complete' =>    'function(){
                            alert("complete");
                        }',
        )
    );
```

In my action in the controller i use reder partial as follows,

```
$this->renderPartial('view',array('model'=>$this->loadModel()),false,true);
```

as i have set processOutput to true, the ajax submit button works fine. But it keeps on executing(for the number of times that i have clicked). I want it to execute only once when the submit button is clicked. 
It'll be great if anyone could help me out with this. I have been trying to fix this all day.

Comment: Possible XSS: `t_store='.$_GET['gift_store'].'&`

Comment: as in?? i dnt get it....

Comment: oh! ya i got it. yea ill be changing that. that doesnt answer my question though.

Answer (score 4):

okay i solved the solution. What is happening is,
The ajax request are triggered based on the ID. Every time the div is reloaded through ajax a new delegate/event will be loaded pointing at the same ID of the one before him. So when you actually click on the button both delegates will do their job, because both match the clicked button.

there are two solutions to this problem. One is having a unique id each time the button is generated like as follows,

```
array('id' => 'next-category-'.uniqid());
```

The other way, and this is how i solved it,

```
array("id"=>"next-category", "live"=>false);
```

live: boolean, whether the event handler should be attached with live/delegate or direct style. If not set, liveEvents will be used.Giving this to the submit button solved it.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of jQuery, you can define the following code to "complete" function:

```
function() {
    $('input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

So on successful completion of your button will be disabled for re-push, if I understand you correctly.

Don't forget to modify the css selector input[type=submit] to the CSS selector your button.

**Solution 2**: Wap your CHtml::ajaxButton into

```
if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {

}
```

Then when you load content via ajax your button will not be displayed on the page

Comment: ok... no i think u have got the wrong idea. sorry my bad. Ok the problem is, say i clicked on the submit button. when i do, it loads the same view with the same button. and when i click on it again it executes the method twice. I want a way of preventing it. any idea?

Comment: When... wrap your CHtml::ajaxButton into `if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {}` then when you load content via ajax your button will not be displayed on the page.

Comment: no i want the button to render. What happens is, the second time i click on the button it calls the action twice. i want it to call the action only once.

Comment: i still didnt get a solution.. is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Better if you create normalizeUrl for ajax request.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
            '>', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/shop/category/nextCategory',array('store'=>1,'gift_store'=>1,'startValue'=>1,'endValue'=>1))), array(
            'type'=>'GET',
            'update'=>'#test',
            'beforeSend' => 'function(){
                            alert("beforeSend");
                            }',
            'complete' =>    'function(){
                                alert("complete");
                            }',
            )
        );
```

This code is perfect, i have checked. It seems that their may be some error somewhere in your js code .

Comment: ya theres nothing wrong with that. It is with the renderPartial. since i have set processOutput to true, it keeps on executing the client script.